# javascript formato de fechas ¿como cambiar formato de fecha?

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo problemas con el formato de fechas mi codigo es el siguiente

```
fecha = new Date();
    entrega = new Date();
    dia = fecha.getDate();
    mes = fecha.getMonth()+1;// +1 porque los meses empiezan en 0
    anio = fecha.getFullYear();
  entrega.setMonth(entrega.getMonth() + 4);

var d = new Date();
var strDate = d.getFullYear() + "-0" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-0" + d.getDate();


    var mesMax="-0"+entrega.getMonth();
    console.log(mesMax);
    var fechaMas = d.getFullYear()+mesMax+"-0"+d.getDate();
    console.log(fechaMas);

    console.log($('#fei').val());
   console.log('fecha compara si es menor');
   console.log(strDate);
     if($('#fei').val()>fechaMas)
     {
      swal('ERROR!','La fecha seleccionada es mayor a 3 meses','error').then($('#fei').val(strDate));

     }else if($('#fei').val()<strDate){
      swal('ERROR!','La fecha seleccionada es menor a la actual','error').then($('#fei').val(strDate));
     }else{console.log('no es mayor');}
```

Esta bien y todo pero el problema es que por ejemplo hoy es el dia 4 de enero y me imprime 4 yo quiero que sea 04, igual para el mes este mes es 01 y me imprime 1, por eso en el código tengo que agregarle el 0 antes, como pudiera resolver eso para no estarlo cambiando para que ya me lo de, al momento de validar me da problemas por eso ocupo el formato, algún consejo?

ok ya pude puse solo una validación

```
if((d.getMonth()+1)<=9){cero = "-0"+(d.getMonth()+1)}else{cero=(d.getMonth()+1)}
```

y con eso soluciono lo demas

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo la libería  [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/), te ayudará mucho con el manejo de fechas y horas, en javascript a veces se complica el manejo de estos tipos de datos.

Importar la librería (CDN) o descarga la librería e importala desde el directorio local

Para obtener la fecha actual lo hacés utilizando `moment()`, para darle formato podés hacerlo de esta manera moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') o bien moment.format('YYYYMMDD') si lo necesitás si guiones.

Y finalmente para obtener el mes y el día como lo necesitás lo realizas de esta manera (para el día actual)

```
let dia = moment().format('DD')
let mes = moment().format('MM')
```

Si necesitás pasarle alguna fecha que necesitás obtener su valor en día y mes lo haces de esta manera:

```
let miFecha = new Date()
console.log(moment(miFecha).format('DD'))
console.log(moment(miFecha).format('MM'))
```

Saludos,

Comment: responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, editala y coloca todo lo importante aquí

Answer (score 0):

Yo utilizo una función que me regresa los números con ese formato para los meses y días.

```
limpiarNumero( n: number ) {
  return n < 10 ? `0${n}` : n.toString();
}

let ddia = limpiarNumero(5); // 05
let mmes = limpiarNumero(15); // 15
```